# ¿Como activar una animación hecha desde Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Hola mi pregunta es como yo puedo activar una animación desde código en unity, porque me ha surgido un problema al crear mi primera animación con mi script de c corría bien pero al también activar otra resulta que el gameObject de la segunda animación que era el mismo de la primera pero con diferente animación se hacia la misma animación que el primero. Elimine la primera animación y solo deje la segunda animación y al ejecutar mi script no se activa. Soy novato en esto de la animación.

código:

```
public AnimationClip a;
Animation b;
;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    b.AddClip (a, "clip");


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    b.Play("clip");
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba primero depurando el Play y dime que valor te devolvería lo siguiente:
bool p = b.Play("clip");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución ha este problema es seleccionando el VideoClip y entrar en el inspector y cambiarlo a Debug y luego ahí se encuentra una opción llamada legacy pisar en ella y luego agregar el VideoClip al componente Animation y ejecutarlo desde código así:

```
Animation anima;
    void Start () {
    anima = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();

}

y luego iniciar la animación con este código:

anima.Play ("Nombre de la animación");
```